# Installing m2e plugin - RAD 7.5.5

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, rad

I am trying to install the m2e plugin so that I can begin experimenting with Maven. I looked towards the m2e download page and was directed [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/) but it is throwing a 404 error. Can anyone provide any more guidance on how to integrate this plugin with RAD 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27017217), RAD 7.5.5 is based on an old version of Eclipse. m2e is unlikely to work, but its predecessor m2eclipse might. Hopefully you will be able to find it as explained [here](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/24316542.html?__utma=246996102.149850775.1375182031.1375182031.1375186658.2&__utmb=246996102.0.10.1375186658&__utmc=246996102&__utmx=-&__utmz=246996102.1375186658.2.2.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=82544917).

However m2e evolved a lot in the last few years and I'd suggest that you switch to a more recent version of Eclipse, if you can. The latest versions actually have m2e directly integrated.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about the out-of-box support for it in more recent IDE's. Unfortunately RAD 7.5 is a requirement. Thanks for your reply.